# Spring and @Autowired - when does the autowiring take place?

Tags: spring, singleton, autowired

I have a class that works like so:

```
@Component
public class MyClass
{

  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
  {
    ...
  }

  public void doSomethingUsingDataSource()
  {
    // use autowired datasource
  }
}
```

My applicationContext.xml contains this:

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />
```

This works fine if I instantiate a MyClass in another class:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.doSomethingUsingDataSource();
```

However, if MyClass is instead a singleton:

```
@Component
public class MyClass
{
  private static MyClass mc;

  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
  {
    ...
  }

  private void doSomethingUsingDataSource()
  {
    // use autowired datasource
  }

  public static void doSomething()
  {
    if (mc == null)
    {
      mc = new MyClass();
    }
    mc.doSomethingUsingDataSource();
  }
}
```

and I call

```
MyClass.doSomething();
```

then I get a NPE because dataSource is null.

Is Spring unable to set the datasource if a new instance of my class is created in this way?  Or do I need to change my configuration a bit?  Since the first version works it appears my configuration is correct.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Your first example shouldn't work either.

Comment: Why not? It does work - perhaps I missed something in my simplification.

Comment: You must've done. Object instantiated with `new` don't get their dependencies wired without some fancy-pants AOP config, like load-time-weaving. Do you have that?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited question to include a snippet of my configuration.

Comment: What actually contains the `mc` field? It's not clear from your code.

Comment: Ack...that was a typo.  Fixed it.

Comment: We're getting there :) The `mc` field is also static, I assume? It won't compile, otherwise.  Also, who calls `doSomething()`, and when do they call it?

Comment: That will teach me to try to simplify things :)  Yes, mc is static, and doSomething is called by some object, not during startup or shutdown, but perhaps in response to a user request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I worked it out by removing the autowiring.  I made my class implement ApplicationContextAware and set the data source in the setApplicationContext method, like so:

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException
{
  setDataSource((DataSource) ac.getBean("dataSource"));
}
```

By doing this I was able to keep my class a singleton with static methods.

Paul